# Using different classpaths for a type at runtime in java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, legacy

I am working on a legacy/ migration project. Therefore both, the new and the old way should be possible. That means, that some classes/services should be used with old imports as well as with new ones. For example those two imports should be used dependent on a property in in application.properties and if possible at runtime exchanged.

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQDestination
org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination
```

I have read of a maven shade plugin, but I don't get it completely and I am not sure, if it is the right thing, that I need.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Why do you need to use the implementation class directly instead of just the `javax.jms.Destination` class provided by the JMS API? The API exists to avoid issues like this in application code.

Comment: You are right. I did it that way then.

Answer (score 1):

```
Based on env variable use 

if(condition1){
 Class.forName("org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQDestination")
}
if(condition2){
  Class.forName("org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination")
}
```

Comment: Do I have to initialize it to a class variable somehow? E.g. I need it for a statement like this and have to set the class for the destination: publisher.publishEvent(new QueueCreateEvent( **new ActiveMQDestination** (newDestination.getQueueName())));

Comment: You need to write code inside that if condition only. If you need class level variable you need to add lot of if else conditions based on the env variable name.

Class x=  Class.forName("org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQDestination")
ActiveMQDestination destination = x.newInstance();
destination.method1()